# Template with multiple ui-views -> Show a state in one ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My index page looks like:

```
{{#content "left"}}
    <div ui-view="viewLeft"></div>
{{/content}}

{{#content "main"}}
    <div ui-view="viewMain"></div>
{{/content}}
```

In "viewLeft" I'd like to have a menu with links that load/show various states in "viewMain". I cannot figure our how to do this :(

My module definition looks like:

```
angular
    .module('__MODULE__.projektbeteiligung', ['ui.router'])

    .config(function ($stateProvider) {$stateProvider
        .state('projektbeteiligung', {
            url: '/projektbeteiligung',
            views: {
                "viewLeft": {
                    templateUrl: 'projektbeteiligung/projektbeteiligungLeft.tpl.html'
                },
                "viewMain": {
                    templateUrl: 'projektbeteiligung/projektbeteiligung.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'ProjektbeteiligungController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('antrag_informationen', {
            url: '/antrag_informationen',
            views: {
                "viewLeft": {
                    templateUrl: 'projektbeteiligung/projektbeteiligungLeft.tpl.html'
                },
                "viewMain": {
                    templateUrl: 'projektbeteiligung/antrag_informationen.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'AntragInformationenController'
                }
            }
        })
        ;
    });
```

Somehow this works but I'd like to avoid reloading "viewLeft".

Comment: You can use nested states. There would be a parent state which will load the left navigation.

Comment: get idea from here http://plnkr.co/edit/eiX5Q0cJPw7YjcqnoVa4?p=preview